# Can't import UDF from python to Excel using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am using python to write a function and then using xlwings I am trying to import it into Excel but I faced the following error:

[image]

My xlwings version is `0.28.5`, and python's is `3.10`, and I am using Excel 2013. also both
`xlwings32-0.28.5.dll` and `xlwings64-0.28.5` are in the same folder as the python3.10.exe

[image]

the name of the python file and Excel file are the same as instructed by the [documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/udfs.html)

I have also tried specifying the python interpreter path in the interpreter box located in the xlwings ribbon in Excel but with no results. I have read the following issues but also with no result:

1. [issue766](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/766)
2. [issue764](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/764)

my python function :

[image]

finally I have obviously added the xlwings add-in in Excel, and I trust access to the VBA project object model

**NOTE:** [Run Python](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/vba.html) works just fine with no error.

so, can anyone point to what I am doing wrong or missing?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by uninstalling the python version that I have and the reinstalling it using anaconda3 distribution. after that from the anaconda prompt type `xlwings addin install` and every thing worked fine.